# scrollview inside linearlayout forces buttons offscreen

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to build an activity that has a checkbox on top, a button at the bottom, and a bunch of other widgets scrolling in between.  Conceptually that's

LinearLayout
 CheckBox
 ScrollView
  LinearLayout
   [stuff]
  LinearLayout-end
 ScrollView-end
 Button
LinearLayout-end

When it renders I get the checkbox at the top, the stuff scrolling nicely underneath, but the Button drawn offscreen (I assume) below the ScrollView.  The only way I can get the Button to be visible is to hard-code the height of the ScrollView, which of course only works on one screen-size.  I've tried all combinations of gravity and layout_weight I can think of to no avail.  Am I using the right combination of Views?  Anybody managed to get this working?

(I don't think RelativeLayout is quite the right container for this, but regardless I hope to avoid it since it's broken on 1.5.)

Thanks,

--Eric

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem recently and I added:

```
<ScrollView 
    ...
    android:layout_weight="1" >
```

that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this in 2.2, not sure if the layout_above and layout_below tags are available in 1.5 (if thats what your using).
Layout your three main elements, the header, the footer and your central content (in this case a list view) that you want to fill the remaining area with.

You could replace the Listview with a scrollView if you wanted, or any component for that matter.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Top Button"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Button"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Note the order of your elements. Not sure its relevant but the center element is defined last.